# PHP configure not finding LDAP header libraries

Tags: linux, php, ldap

I installed the LDAP development headers:

`apt-get install libldb-dev`

This added a few ldap headers:

```
root@crunchbang:/usr/include# ls -la ldap*
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  9466 Apr 23  2013 ldap_cdefs.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  1814 Apr 23  2013 ldap_features.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 65213 Apr 23  2013 ldap.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  9450 Apr 23  2013 ldap_schema.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  3468 Apr 23  2013 ldap_utf8.h
```

When I configure and reference the directory:

`./configure --with-ldap=/usr/include`

I get this error:

```
...
checking for LDAP support... yes
checking for LDAP Cyrus SASL support... no
checking size of long int... 4
configure: error: Cannot find ldap libraries in /usr/include.
```

Comment: How is a question about *compiling PHP* off-topic for server fault?  Are no less than FIVE moderators truly unaware that PHP is a ubiquitous "information technology system used in business environments" and that IT professionals are commonly tasked with managing it?  Do they not realize that compiling server software is a bread-and-butter System Administration task?  There is no valid reason to close this question and it being "off topic" is just flat-out absurd.

Comment: @Goladus Thank you! Yes. Not sure how this is NOT server related.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I ran into this issue trying to get PHP extensions involved in a Docker container.  Here is what I had to do:

1. `apt-get install libldb-dev libldap2-dev`
2. `ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libldap.so /usr/lib/libldap.so \
   && ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblber.so /usr/lib/liblber.so`

Comment: Dockerfile.......
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
libldap2-dev \
libldb-dev \
&& ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libldap.so /usr/lib/libldap.so \
&& ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblber.so /usr/lib/liblber.so

Answer (score 9):

This worked for me perfectly.

Install LDAP libraries:

`apt-get install libldb-dev`

Create SO linker files:

```
updatedb --prunepaths=/mnt
cd /usr/lib

if [ ! -L liblber-2.4.so.2 ];
then
    ln -s "$(locate liblber-2.4.so.2)"
fi

if [ ! -L liblber-2.4.so.2.8.3 ];
then
    ln -s "$(locate liblber-2.4.so.2.8.3)"
fi

if [ ! -L liblber.so ];
then
    ln -s "$(locate liblber.so)"
fi

if [ ! -L libldap.so ];
then
    ln -s "$(locate libldap.so)"
fi

if [ ! -L libldap_r.so ];
then
    ln -s "$(locate libldap_r.so)"
fi
```

Configure PHP:

`./configure --with-ldap=/usr`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. For Ubuntu Trusty, after installing libldb-dev, the following is sufficient: `sudo ln -s /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/liblber.so /usr/lib`, `sudo ln -s /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libldap.so /usr/lib`.

Comment: Also, make sure you are not specifying lib64 libraries path as that is a sure-fire way of making sure compilation fails. This is the actual fix!

      --with-libdir=lib64 \ 

//This is what I am referring to

Answer (score 5):

The cleanest way to do it, according to [this comment](https://github.com/docker-library/php/issues/75#issuecomment-82075678) in the issues of the official PHP Docker image, is using `libldap2-dev` (in Debian/Ubuntu) and calling `configure` with `--with-libdir=lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`.

Answer (score 2):

PHP Version 5.6.20
debian and based:

`su
aptitude install libldb-dev
ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libldap.so /usr/lib/libldap.so`

then, try to compile it

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue and none of the answers above helped. Then after some digging into PHP's configure file I found a different solution.

1) Check which lib directoriy you are using. If you use the switch `--with-libdir=lib64` then you should have the `libldap.so` and the other `.so` files in `/usr/lib64`. If you are not specifying a libdir then the `.so` files should be in `/usr/lib`. You can create symlinks if the `.so` file are in a non-standard directory (like `/usr/lib64`) but you dont want to specify the libdir.

2) Use the switch `--with-ldap=yes`

I wonder why this is not documented in the configure help.

Comment: For me --with-ldap=yes found.

Answer (score 0):

(Assuming you're on Ubuntu) Please try `configure --with-ldap-libs=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/`. If doesn't help, please extend your answer with details on which Linux distro do you use and which project you're building.

Comment: Tried it. Doesn't work.
`configure: error: Cannot find ldap libraries in /usr/lib.`

Comment: Updated the answer. Please follow-up.

Comment: I don't think --with-ldap-libs is an option. I've tried --with-ldap-dir and it seemed to work but when I tried to use a php ldap function it didn't work.